# How to get user profile URL of Facebook with Firebase Authentication?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, facebook, firebase-authentication

I follow the docs of Firebase for Facebook login, it work but i don't see anything relate user profile link of Facebook, Am i missing something?

code in the docs of Firebase.

```
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, FacebookAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;
    // I don't see any properties in user relate with user profile link of Facebook

    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const accessToken = credential.accessToken;

    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message)

    // ...
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such URL provided.  I suggest reviewing the [documentation for the User interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user) and its [UserInfo parent interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.userinfo.md#userinfo_interface) to find out what sort of data you have access to after the user signs in.